# Problem using Bayes Rule

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability

I own a dog that I don't always remember to feed in the morning before work. By the time I get home from work, I remember whether or not I fed the dog. I feed the dog 60% of the time. If I feed the dog, he is hungry 10% of the time when I get back from work. If I don't feed him, he is hungry 70% of the time. I came home last night to find that my dog is hungry. How likely is it that I fed the dog that morning?
This is what I have so far:
$P(F)=6/10,P(H|F)=1/10,P(H|NF)=7/10),P(NF)=4/10$
We want to find $P(F|H)$ and by Bayes law $P(F|H)=\frac{P(H|F)P(F)}{P(H)}=\frac{1/10 \cdot 6/10}{P(H)}$
Now what I am having trouble with is finding  $P(H)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sum, or integrate, over the joint distribution, in this case of whether the your dog is hungry or not, and whether you feed your dog, or not. Since $P(A, B) = P(A \vert B) P(B)$, you find that
$$P(H) = P(H \vert F)P(F) + P(H\vert NF)P(NF) = \frac{1}{10}\frac{6}{10} + 
\frac{7}{10}\frac{4}{10} = \frac{17}{50}.$$
By total probability we also have immediately that
$$P(NH) = 1 - P(H) = \frac{33}{50}.$$

In general, you have for discrete variables $X$ and $Y$ that

$$P(X=x) = \sum_{y} P(X=x, Y=y) = \sum_{y} P(X=x\vert Y=y)P(Y=y),$$
where the sum is taken over all possible values of $Y$.